# How to fix Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a simple React components that fetches data from the database using Axios, it works but when I open the console I notice the following error:

```
index.js:1375 Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method.
```

As far I read to fix it you need to use componentDidMount with a conditional statement, but I don't know how to apply that using the `useEffect` hook. How can I fix the error? Here is my attempt:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import SecondColumn from '../SecondColumn/SecondColumn';
import Text from '../Text/Text';
import Pagination from "react-pagination-js";
import Spinner from '../Spinner/Spinner';

const Posts = () => {

  let [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [postsPerPage] = useState(5);
  const isMounted = useRef(false)
  const GET_POSTS_API = process.env.REACT_APP_GET_POSTS_API;

  useEffect(() => {
    isMounted.current = true;
    const fetchPosts = async () => {
      setLoading(true);
      if (isMounted.current) {
        let res = await axios.get(GET_POSTS_API);
        setPosts(res.data);
        setLoading(false);
      }

    };

    fetchPosts();
    return () => { isMounted.current = false }
  }, []);

  // Get current posts
  const indexOfLastPost = currentPage * postsPerPage;
  const indexOfFirstPost = indexOfLastPost - postsPerPage;
  const currentPosts = posts.slice(indexOfFirstPost, indexOfLastPost);

  if (loading) {
    return <Spinner />
  }

  // Change page
  const paginate = (pageNumber) => {
    if (pageNumber > 0) {
      setCurrentPage(pageNumber);
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="row">
      <div className="column">
        {currentPosts.map(post => (
          <div key={post._id} className='post'>
            <img className="post-container__image" src={post.picture} alt="avatar" />
            <div className="post-container__post">
              <div className="post-container__text">
                <h2 className="post-container__title">{post.title}</h2>
                <p className="post-container__date">{post.date}</p>
                <p className="post-info-container__text">{post.postContent.substring(0, 310) + "..."}</p>
                <Link to={`/post/${post._id}`} className="read-more-btn">
                  <button className="read-more-btn">Read more</button>
                </Link>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        ))}
        <Pagination
          currentPage={currentPage}
          currentPosts={currentPosts}
          showFirstLastPages={true}
          sizePerPage={postsPerPage}
          totalSize={posts.length}
          totalPages={posts.length}
          changeCurrentPage={paginate}
        />
        <Text />
      </div>
      <div className="column">
        <SecondColumn />
      </div>
    </div>
  )
};

export default Posts;
```

After applying all solutions posted here, none seem to remove the error I debugged more and it turns out that in the SecondColumn component I have a component FacebookProvider coming from the react-facebook package. When I remove the component I don't get this error, but I need to have the component on the page, any idea why this package is causing this error and how to fix it? here is the full code of the SecondColumn where the FacebookProvider is located:

```
import React from 'react';
import titles from '../../enums.js'
import { FacebookProvider, Page } from 'react-facebook';
import CustomHeading from '../CustomHeading/CustomHeading.jsx'


class SecondColumn extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return <div className="second-column">

      <div className="second-column__about-me">
        <CustomHeading text={titles.ABOUT_ME} className="astro-heading-margin-left" />
        <img className="second-column__first_part__test-img-col" src={require("../../assets/images/fake-image.png")} alt="fake img for now" />
        <div className="second-column_first_part_text-parent">
          <p className="second-column_first_part_text-parent__text-body">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
          Molestiae molestias tempora ratione dolorum, tenetur laborum blanditiis id  Molestiae molestias tempora ratione dolorum, tenetur laborum blanditiis id
          Molestiae molestias tempora ratione dolorum, tenetur laborum blanditiis id  Molestiae molestias tempora ratione dolorum, tenetur laborum blanditiis id
          Molestiae molestias tempora ratione dolorum, tenetur laborum blanditiis id  Molestiae molestias tempora ratione dolorum, tenetur laborum blanditiis id
           </p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div className="second-column__first_part">
        <CustomHeading text={titles.MY_ASTROLOGICAL_READINGS} className="astro-heading-margin-left" />

        <img className="second-column__first_part__test-img-col" src={require("../../assets/images/fake-image.png")} alt="fake img for now" />
        <img className="second-column__first_part__test-img-col" src={require("../../assets/images/fake-image.png")} alt="fake img for now" />
        <img className="second-column__first_part__test-img-col" src={require("../../assets/images/fake-image.png")} alt="fake img for now" />
        <button className="btn">click here for all readings</button>
      </div>
      <div className="second-column__second_part">
        <h3 className="second-column__second_part__title"> Signs in a nutshell</h3>
        <div className="second-column__second_part__container">
          <div className="item">
            <img className="item__astro-icon" src={require("../../assets/astro-signs/002-aries.png")} alt="aries sign" />
            <p className="title">Aries</p>
          </div>

          <div className="item">
            <img className="item__astro-icon" src={require("../../assets/astro-signs/022-taurus.png")} alt="taurus sign" />
            <p className="title">Taurus</p>
          </div>

          <div className="item">
            <img className="item__astro-icon" src={require("../../assets/astro-signs/007-gemini.png")} alt="taurus sign" />
            <p className="title">Gemini</p>
          </div>
          <div className="item">
            <img className="item__astro-icon" src={require("../../assets/astro-signs/003-cancer.png")} alt="cancer sign" />
            <p className="title">Cancer</p>
          </div>
          <div className="item">
            <img className="item__astro-icon" src={require("../../assets/astro-signs/009-leo.png")} alt="leo sign" />
            <p className="title">Leo</p>
          </div>

          <div className="item">
            <img className="item__astro-icon" src={require("../../assets/astro-signs/025-virgo.png")} alt="virgo sign" />
            <p className="title">Virgo</p>
          </div>
          <div className="item">
            <img className="item__astro-icon" src={require("../../assets/astro-signs/010-libra.png")} alt="libra sign" />
            <p className="title">Libra</p>
          </div>
          <div className="item">
            <img className="item__astro-icon" src={require("../../assets/astro-signs/020-scorpio.png")} alt="scorpio sign" />
            <p className="title">Scorpio</p>
          </div>
          <div className="item">
            <img className="item__astro-icon" src={require("../../assets/astro-signs/018-sagittarius.png")} alt="sagitarius sign" />
            <p className="title">Sagitarius</p>
          </div>
          <div className="item">
            <img className="item__astro-icon" src={require("../../assets/astro-signs/004-capricorn.png")} alt="capricorn sign" />
            <p className="title">Capricorn</p>
          </div>
          <div className="item">
            <img className="item__astro-icon" src={require("../../assets/astro-signs/001-aquarius.png")} alt="aquarius sign" />
            <p className="title">Aquarius</p>
          </div>
          <div className="item">
            <img className="item__astro-icon" src={require("../../assets/astro-signs/016-pisces.png")} alt="pisces sign" />
            <p className="title">Pisces</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="second-column__third_part">
        <CustomHeading text={titles.DISCOVER_MORE_TOPICS} className="astro-heading-no-margin" />
        <div className="second-column__third_part-item">
          <div className="second-column__third-part-item__text">
            <p className="second-column__third-part-item__text_cont_title">Planets in astrology</p>
            <p className="second-column__third-part-item__text-cont">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
            Molestiae molestias tempora ratione dolorum, tenetur laborum blanditiis id

           </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="second-column__third_part-item">
          <div className="second-column__third-part-item__text">
            <p className="second-column__third-part-item__text_cont_title">Houses in Astrology</p>
            <p className="second-column__third-part-item__text-cont">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
            Molestiae molestias tempora ratione dolorum, tenetur laborum blanditiis id
          </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="second-column__third_part-item">
          <div className="second-column__third-part-item__text_cont">
            <p className="second-column__third-part-item__text_cont_title">Astrology Aspects</p>
            <p className="second-column__third-part-item__text-cont">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
            Molestiae molestias tempora ratione dolorum, tenetur laborum blanditiis id
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
      <div className="second-column__fourth_part">
        <CustomHeading text={titles.CONNECT_WITH_ME_ON_FACEBOOK} className="astro-heading-no-margin" />
        <FacebookProvider appId="156975948863691">
          <Page href="https://www.facebook.com/UserName" tabs="timeline" />
        </FacebookProvider>
      </div>
    </div>
  }

};

export default SecondColumn;
```

Comment: If would be nice if you could accept one of the answers or if they do not solve your problem, comment them and explain why

Comment: I updated my question, it turns out that the FacebookProvider component is causing this error located in the SecondColumn component, when I remove it the error goes away, but I need this component, the docs https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-facebook don't offer any solution

Comment: useEffect should return a function, not some code to execute. Look at my answer, the last line of your useEffect should be:  `return {() => { isMounted.current = false }`

Comment: You're checking `isMounted.current` before the `axios.wait`. You should test it after. You should call `axios.wait` first, then if `isMounted.current` is true, you can call `setPosts` and `setLoading`.

Right now, your `isMounted` is completely useless

Answer (score 0):

In order for your variables to be persisted across renders, you need to define them using useRef

Also the isMounted variable can be updated using an useEffect cleanup function.

However since you are  asynchronously updating state only in  useEffect, you can simply define a variable in useEffect

```
      useEffect(() => {
        const isMounted = true;
        const fetchPosts = async () => {
          setLoading(true);
          if (isMounted) {
            let res = await axios.get(GET_POSTS_API);
            setPosts(res.data);
          }
          setLoading(false);
        };

        fetchPosts();
        // cleanup function
        return () => { isMounted = false; }
      }, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

`isMounted` doesn't need to be state, it can just be a reference:

```
const isMounted = useRef(false);
```

Then in your useEffect, you can set it to true:

```
useEffect(() => {
    isMounted.current = true;
```

Your useEffect function can also return a function that will be called before unMounting your component, this is where you can set your isMounted back to false:

```
useEffect(() => {
    isMounted.ref = true;
    ...
    return {() => { isMounted.current = false }
}, []);
```

To test if your component is mounted, you do:

```
if (isMounted.current) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the example to prevent:

```
  useEffect(() =&gt; {
let isCancelled = false;
const runAsync = async () =&gt; {
  try {
    if (!isCancelled) {
      // do the job
    }
  } catch (e) {
    if (!isCancelled) {
      throw e;
    }
  }
};

runAsync();

return () =&gt; {
  isCancelled = true;
};
```

}, [...]);

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you don't need `isMounted`, because your `useEffect` hook only runs once due to the empty dependencies array (it is similar to `componentDidMount`).

This error tells you that you need to clean up your fetch call in `useEffect`.

I have two methods:

1. **Simple**: use a token/flag to skip the state update when the component unmounts.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const isCanceled = false;

  const fetchPosts = async () => {
    setLoading(true);
    let res = await axios.get(GET_POSTS_API);
    if (!isCanceled) {
      setPosts(res.data);
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };

  fetchPosts();

  return () => {
    isCanceled = true;
  };
}, []);
```

2. **Recommended**: Cancel your request
   With axios, you can use `CancelToken`. (Read more here: https://github.com/axios/axios#cancellation)

```
useEffect(() => {
  const source = axios.CancelToken.source();

  const fetchPosts = async () => {
    setLoading(true);

    try {
      let res = await axios.get(GET_POSTS_API, {
        cancelToken: source.token
      });
      setPosts(res.data);
      setLoading(false);
    } catch (error) {
      if (axios.isCancel(error)) {
        //cancelled
      } else {
        throw error;
      }
    }
  };

  fetchPosts();

  return () => {
    source.cancel();
  };
}, []);
```